# How to find the index of a word in a string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, search

In bash script,

I have a string which contains several words separated by one or more than one spaces.
ie:

```
Name   Age Sex  ID         Address
```

If I want to find any of the word, for instance I want to find the index of word "Age", how can I do it?

Is there any command that will return the index number of the word I want directly?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the solution have to be strictly in bash? Or can awk, grep, etc. be used?

Comment: Related post: [How to print certain columns by name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/how-to-print-certain-columns-by-name)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bash performs [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) in strings all by itself – in fact, more often than not, avoiding that is an issue, and the reason quoting is so important. It’s easy to leverage that in your case: just put your string into an array without quoting it – bash will use word splitting to separate the individual elements. Assuming your string is stored in the variable `$str`,

```
ar=($str) # no quotes!
```

will return an array of 5 elements. Your array index is your word index (counting up from 0, like in most scripting and programming languages), i.e. “Age” is accessed using

```
${ar[1]}  # 0 => Name, 1 => Age, 2 => Sex, 3 => ID, 4 => Address
```

or, if you need to find the element index by content, loop over the array, i.e.

```
function el_index {
    cnt=0; for el in "${ar[@]}"; do
        [[ $el == "$1" ]] && echo $cnt && break
        ((++cnt))
    done
}
el_index "Age" # => 1
```

Comment: wow...i didn't know that without the quotes then it would be an array. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
$ export FOO="Name   Age Sex  ID         Address"
```

Replace *Age with Age -- this will remove anything before "Age":

```
$ echo ${FOO/*Age/Age}
Age Sex ID Address
```

Get anything before "Age"

```
$ echo ${FOO/Age*/}
Name
```

Get the length of that string (which is the index of "Age"):

```
$ BEGIN=${FOO/Age*/}
$ echo ${#BEGIN}
7
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but wow! Slick trick. It even works in ash, and with embedded variables: `export L='debug info warn error'; export GTE='warn'; echo ${L/*${GTE}/${GTE}}` prints 'warn error'

Answer (score 1):

This is a 7-years-old question, but some may need the answer in pure bash.

```bash
STRING="Name   Age Sex  ID         Address"
INDEXOF_AGE=${#${STRING/Age*/}}
echo $INDEXOF_AGE
```

Comment: gives error on bash 5.0.17(1) at least: `bash: ${#${STRING/Age*/}}: bad substitution` but I get it, it is the size of the remaining string

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: Assuming here that by index you mean you want to know which *word* it is (starting from 0), not which *character* in the string the word starts on. Other answers address the latter.

Not that I'm aware of, but you can make one. Two tricks:

1. Use the inborn abilities of the *for* construct to split up an unquoted input by whitespace.
2. Handle the case where you can't find the column you want. In this case, I chose to send the found index to stout and let the status code indicate whether the find was successful. There are other possibilities.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
find_index() {
    local str=$1
    local search=$2
    let local n=0
    local retval=1 # here, 1 is failure, 0 success
    for col in $str; do # $str unquoted -> whitespace tokenization!
    if [ $col = $search ]; then
        echo $n
        retval=0
        break
    else
        ((n++))
    fi
    done
    return $retval
}

test="Name   Age Sex  ID         Address"
idx=`find_index "$test" Age`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Not found!"
else
    echo "Found: $idx"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to strictly use bash, but can use other programs commonly found on systems with bash then you could use something like this:

```
echo "Name   Age Sex ID  Addr" | python -c 'print(raw_input().index("Age"))+1'
```

Python starts its string indexing at zero, therefore I added +1 to the end of the command.

Comment: "its string indexing", without the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash's native regex

```
# a function to print the index of a field and its name
printIx() { 
  for ((l=0,i=1;i<$1;i++)) ;do 
     ((l+=${#BASH_REMATCH[i]}))
  done
  printf '%3s %s\n' $l "$2"
}

#   Using a zero based index
#   "0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4"
str="  Name   Age Sex  ID         Address   "

if [[ $str =~ ^(\ *)(Name)(\ +)(Age)(\ +)(Sex)(\ +()ID)(\ +)(Address)\ *$ ]] ;then
  F=(Name Age Sex ID Address)
  f=(   2   4   6  8      10)  # regex back-references
  for ((g=0;g<${#f[@]};g++)) ;do
     printIx  ${f[g]} "${F[g]}"
  done 
fi
```

Output

```
  2 Name
  9 Age
 13 Sex
 20 ID
 29 Address
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following javascript oneliner in a shell (use javascript shell) :

```
$ js <<< "x = 'Name   Age Sex  ID         Address'; print(x.indexOf('Age'));"
7
```

Or with a here-doc:

```
js <<EOF
x = 'Name   Age Sex  ID         Address';
print(x.indexOf('Age'));
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works fine.

> $ string='now is the time' 
>  $ buf=the${string#*the} 
>  $ echo
>   $buf 
>  output: the time 
>  $ index=$(( ${#string} - ${#buf} + 1
>   )) 
>  $ echo $index 
>  output: 8 -> index of first word "the"

It works similar as function indexOf() in Java which returns first occurrence of an input string.

Found this solution in here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-string-manipulation-help-670627/ (last post). 
This guy saved my day. Credit to him.

Faster way if you want to do substring from first indexof.

> $ a="some long string" 
>  
>   $ b="ri" 
>  $ echo ${a/*$b/$b} 
>  
>   ring 
>   $ echo ${a/$b*/$b} 
>  
>   some long stri

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349102/shell-script-substring-from-first-indexof-substring

Answer (score 0):

If coreutils are available you can do it in following way:

> echo ${str/Age//}| cut -d/ -f1| wc -w

Per MariusMatutiae request I'm adding an explanation how this 3 steps operation works:

> echo ${str/Age//} *1. replace string which is being searched for unique char (in my case /)*
>
> cut -d/ -f1  *2. cut off whole part of string which is after unique char*
>
> wc -w *3. count and print words which are left this will give us an index number*

For references please check:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html (go to: "Variable expansion / Substring replacement")
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html (go to: "The cut command" and "wc invocation"

Comment: While this solves the problem at hand, such terse replies are frowned upon in these sites. It would be more helpful to spend a few words explaining exactly why this works. Please do so.

Answer (score 0):

A mix of two previously given answers, using pure bash arrays and substring replacement.

The idea is to get a string of all words before the one you want, then count the number of words in that substring by making it into an array.

```
$ haystack="Name   Age Sex  ID         Address"
$ words_before=( ${haystack%Age*} )     # truncate string, make array
$ echo ${#words_before[*]}              # count words in array
1
```

Of course Age can be stored in another variable `needle`, then use `${haystack%$needle*}`. Expect problems if the word you search for is a subset of another word, in which case kopischke's answer is still working.

Answer (score 0):

the size of the remaining string after the erasure using `wc -c` so that you dont need to create an intermediary string variable

```
str="Name   Age Sex  ID         Address";
nIndex="`echo -n "${str/Age*/}" |wc -c`";
declare -p nIndex
```

declare -- nIndex="7"

Btw, this may be useful info: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/